# compare line by line: two files in unix

Tags: file, unix

PFB the scenario. I have two files

file1

```
firstName1 LastName1
FirstName2 LastName2
```

File2

```
FirstName1 LastName1
FirstName2 LastName2
```

Now I want to compare  FirstName1 of file1 with that of file2. If it matches then compare   LastName1 of file1 with that of File2.

If any of these values doesn't mach then the record should be written to log file.

Once we have done this, move to second record.

Can some one put some insight into it......

Comment: First: Welcome to SO. This might help you getting along with SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  To answer you question [`diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) is the tool you need

Answer (score 0):

Use following standard unix commands

```
diff
sdiff
```

This [page](http://javatechjourney.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-diff-and-sdiff.html) will also help to understand difference between diff and sdiff.

You can also write a script to compare records from the 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

diff is the best for what you want to do, but here is a snippet if you want more actions in that kind of situation, assuming the files are properly formatted

```
./compare.sh <file1> <file2>
```

compare.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

line_number=0

cat $1 | while read line_f1; do

    line_number=$((line_number + 1))

    line_f2=$(cat $2 | sed "${line_number}q;d")

    echo "line f1 : ${line_f1}"
    echo "line f2 : ${line_f2}"

    firstname_f1=$(echo ${line_f1} | cut -f1 -d' ')
    firstname_f2=$(echo ${line_f2} | cut -f1 -d' ')
    lastname_f1=$(echo ${line_f1} | cut -f2 -d' ')
    lastname_f2=$(echo ${line_f2} | cut -f2 -d' ')

    echo "firstname f1 : ${firstname_f1}"
    echo "firstname f2 : ${firstname_f2}"
    echo "lastname f1 : ${lastname_f1}"
    echo "lastname f2 : ${lastname_f2}"

    if [ ! "${firstname_f1}" = "${firstname_f2}" ]; then
        echo "Differents Firstnames"
    fi

    #... place here other tests ...

done
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply.. whats the file name used here ? is it f1 ? what you mean by cat $1 at the begining ... Thanks in advance..

Comment: actually the script take your 2 files as arguments `cat $1` will read the first file (argument) and you have a `cat $2` later in the script for the second file (argument). I edited it so it's more clear.